# Python's profile module: <string>:1(?)

Tags: python, profiling, profiler, profile

I am using Python's (v2.4) `profile` module to profile a `numpy` script, and the following entry appears to account for the bulk of the execution time:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
 256/1    0.000    0.000    7.710    7.710 <string>:1(?)
```

Unfortunately, its appearance makes it hard to Google.

How do I go about figuring out what this is exactly?

**edit** The profiler is run from the shell as follows: `python -m profile -s cumulative script.py`

Comment: Are you using `profile.run()` to run the profiler?  Then `<string>:1` refers to the first line of the statement string you passed to this function.  If you are calling the profiler in a different way, please specify.

Comment: @Sven Marnach: Good point, I've added this info to the question.

Comment: Assuming you're asking because you want higher performance, [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295799/how-to-improve-performance-of-this-code/4299378#4299378).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Ignore this line.  It is an artifact of how the profiler is implemented.  It is not telling you anything useful.  Look at the "tottime" value for it: 0.000.  "tottime" is the amount of time spent executing "<string>:1(?)" excluding time spent executing children of it.  So, no time is spent here.  "cumtime" and "percall" are large because they include time spent in children.  See http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html#cProfile.run for more details.

Comment: but what if the *largest* tottime is `<string>:1(<module>)`?

Comment: `<string>:1(<module>)` is top-level code in the entry-point Python script invoked.  So if all your code is top-level in "foo.py" and you do `python foo.py`, then you'll see a high tottime for `<string>:1(<module>)`.  By "top-level", I mean not inside any function definition - just run directly.

Comment: if I order the %prun output by tottime I have 8.9 seconds (of 9.6 overall) in <string>:1(<module>). The next entry is 0.2 s and then it decreases quickly. What happens in the top entry?